# Prevent Windows 8 from booting when battery is low

Tags: windows-8, laptop, battery, hibernate

Is there anyway to prevent Windows from booting when the battery is below a certain point (say 20%)?

The reason I ask is that my current computer doesn't have any way to check the battery when it's off. I usually hibernate my computer when I'm going to leave it off for a while, but far too many times when I turn it back on I have just enough battery to get to the login screen before it just dies. This kills the hibernate state, which is super annoying. (Also, it's not really good for the machine.)

I seem to recall seeing a screen like this on earlier versions of Windows, but that have might just been on a Dell. (I'm sure some Dell computers have this feature.)

(I'm not really sure why my computer never seems to have enough energy to restore from hibernate properly. It's not usually that low when it this happens, and I don't have any other trouble with the battery. Maybe it's just bad luck. But seriously, this happens *a lot*. I really can't trust my computer to restore from hibernate on battery anymore.)

Comment: Plug it into the mains before turning it on?

Comment: Well, that's the obvious solution. (That's what the last statement meant.) This usually happens when I think to myself, "It was pretty charged when I turned it off, I should have enough power to start it back up." Of course, I'm quickly proven wrong.

As I said, I remember a few of my computers doing this in the past, which was *super convenient*. "Hey, your battery is low. You should plug your computer in or you might lose data." Basically, I miss that feature.